# Why $x=u+v$ substitution works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the solution for the follwoing example :

> $$x^4+y^4=82$$
>
> $$x-y=2$$

The author substitutes  $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$

My question is: If we have two numbers ($x, y$), can we always find another two numbers ($ u, v$) such that the sum ($ u+ v$)and difference ($ u- v$) of newly found two numbers will give us the original two numbers ? ; What enables us to confidently say that $u+v=x$ and $u-v=y$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\frac12(x+y)$ which surely always exists, and let $v=\frac12(x-y)$ which also surely always exists. Then $u+v=x$ and $u-v=y$ always.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the sum and the difference of your last two equations.

What do you find doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about integer solutions, so first observe that $x,y$ must have same parity modulo 2. Which means $x-y, x+y$ both are divisible by 2. You can always take $v=\frac{x -y}{2}$ and $u=\frac{ x+y}{2}$. Which is why the substitution is possible here.